# Solving Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm wondering why I got this error..

**Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6**

```
     val inputData = readCSVFileLines(fileSystem, inputFile, skipHeader = true).toSeq                                                                                                    
     val filter = inputData.filter(x => x.nonEmpty)                                                                                                                                     
       .map(x => x.split(","))                                                                                                                                                           
       .map(x => Revenue(x(6), x(5), x(0), x(7).toDouble))                                                                                                                               
                                                                                                                                                                                     
 val writer = new PrintWriter(new File(outputFile))                                                                                                                                  
 writer.write("Sales Date,Customer,Article,Revenue,Last Date,Average Last Date,Average Next Date")       
 filter.foreach(x => {                                                                                                                                                              
   val (back90, avgRevenue1) = back90Average(filtinp, x)                                                                                                                             
   val (next30, avgRevenue2) = next30Average(filtinp, x)                                                                                                                             
   writer.write(s"${x.date},${x.customer},${x.article},${x.revenue},${back90},${avgRevenue1},${next30},${avgRevenue2}\n")                                                              
 })                                                                                                                                                                                  
 writer.close()
```

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException Create breakpoint: 6

Comment: Code works flawless with a less number of rows with identical CSV files (exact same column names and number of columns), this is just larger dataset

Comment: this works with first 1000 rows, Why this fails if run with CSV with total amount(396765 rows in total) ??

Comment: worked with 60k rows but fails when trying to process more than 70k rows, performance problem due to local lack of computing/memory (runing it localy in a laptop)?

Comment: It is not performance related, just something in this rows range it is spoiling it

Comment: ok, got it, it's due to empty rows, how do I circumvent this?

Comment: you already filter out empty rows, so this can't be the reason. I guess there are not enough columns or columns are empty. So, add another filter

Comment: hi, actually is due to empty cells, if I remove rows with empty cells this works. How do I filter based on this condition?

Comment: just use the size of the array I'd say?

Comment: sorry, how would this be? already have inputData.filter(x => x.nonEmpty) in the code